# Am I using structs correctly?

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I'm learning multithreading in C currently. For this assignment I have to make a multithreaded Conway's Game of Life. The program takes in a bunch of parameters at execution. Here's all the variables it takes in before execution:

```
./gameoflife <width> <height> <seed> <p> <freq> <#worker_threads>
```

Anyway, in order to make it multithreaded I decided to split the workload vertically between the #worker_threads. So each worker thread has its own widthStart and widthEnd to work on.

Here's what my data structures look like :

```
typedef struct {

    int width;
    int height;
    int ** board; 

    int freq;
    int nbThreads;

    int * escaped;

} masterStruct;

typedef struct {

    int widthStart; 
    int widthEnd;
    int threadID;
    masterStruct * master;    //this is supposed to be a pointer to the struct above.

}paramStruct;
```

Now in my "threader" thread (which is in charge of figuring out widthStart and widthEnd) takes in *masterStruct* as argument. Inside it, I call a bunch of pthread_creates to whom I'll feed *paramsStruct* as an argument. I'd like all these newly created pthreads to all have access to the same global masterStruct. So in my "threader" thread, I declared it as such :

```
paramStruct p[workers]; //create as many paramStruct as nbThreads

for (int i = 0; i < workers; i++) {

    *(p[i].master) = myStr; //give each thread
...
```

**My question is** : Is this the correct way to ensure all the pthreads have access to the same masterStruct?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that in C `*(p[i].master)` is equivalent to `p[i]->master`.

Comment: @glauxosdever I get a " error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ " when I try that.

Comment: That's because they aren't equivalent. Your original use is ok. Had it been `(*p[i]).master` then changing to `p[i]->master` would have made sense. Now, it doesn't.

Comment: @eran Oh my bad. That makes sense.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up precedence. `(*p[i]).master` is equivalent to `p[i]->master`.

Comment: @glauxosdever Do I need to allocate memory for each pointer when assigning them to myStr? I seem to get a segfault every time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing it's not correct. `*(p[i].master) = myStr;` copies `myStr` to some (and I think, invalid) memory. Maybe you want like this: `p[i].master = &myStr;`.